# How to create a login screen using Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Desired result:

[image: Desired result]

Currently my code is as follows:

```
class KeypadButton(Factory.Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            FocusBehavior.ignored_touch.append(touch)
        return super(KeypadButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   
class Keypad(Factory.GridLayout):
    target = Factory.ObjectProperty(None, allownone=True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Keypad, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 3
        for x in list(range(1, 10)) + ['<-', 0, 'Enter']:
            btn = KeypadButton(text=str(x), on_release=self._on_release)
            self.add_widget(btn)

    def _on_focus(self, ti, value):
        self.target = value and ti
            
    def _on_release(self, instance, *largs):
        if self.target:
            if instance.text == 'Enter':
                print("Enter: {}".format(self.target.text))
                self.target.text = ''
            elif instance.text == '<-':
                if self.target.text:
                    self.target.text = self.target.text[:-1]
            else:
                self.target.text += str(instance.text)
    
runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
<KeypadTextInput@TextInput>:
    keypad: None
    on_focus: root.keypad._on_focus(*args)

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    KeypadTextInput:
        keypad: keypad
    Keypad:
        id: keypad
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
'''))
```

What I want to achieve is that when I press 12345 the login screen disappears and a new screen pop ups. I have an image of the format that is given by the following what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly how close you want to get to your desired result, but you can get much closer by just changing your 'kv' to:

```
<KeypadTextInput@TextInput>:
    keypad: None
    on_focus: root.keypad._on_focus(*args)

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    KeypadTextInput:
        keypad: keypad
    Keypad:
        id: keypad
        size_hint_x: 0.5
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem that the text input is automatically focused on it. Now I need to click on it; enter password en then press enter. In the desired result; there are also 5 rectangle boxes that you fill and then it automatically check if the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First when it comes to the issue of focus, I think it depends on how you load up the screen. Is it your root widget or a screen you load up?
As yours looks to be a root widget of sorts you'd probably want to do this with the start up of your app. You can use the 'on_start' event for this

```
class MyApp(App):
    def on_start(self,*args):
        self.ids.mytextinput.focus = True   #replace mytextinput with whatever id name you give to your text input in the kv string
```

For the text input firing off events when you type a certain number of digits you could use on_text. For this I think it's best to instantiate your own class if you're starting out.

```
class KeyPadTextInput(TextInput):
    def on_text(self,*args):
        if len(self.text)==3:
            #put your python code here
            #you can launch MyApp functions by using app.function_name()
```

Another thing I've noticed is that you use on_focus to trigger your own '_on_focus' event with the same *args. You could achieve the same thing by removing the on_focus from your kv string and adjusting the class on_focus event, calling super().on_focus(*args) so the inherited function also fires as such:

```
class KeyPadTextInput(TextInput):
    def on_focus(self,*args):
        #your code either before the super call
        super().on_focus(*args)
        #or your code after the super call
```

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.

PS. TextInputs have a few prebuilt input filters such as a filter so you can only input numbers! This is handy if the users keyboard comes up or they have access to one too.
in the kv string simply add

```
input_filter: 'int'
```

Comment: Hey can you perhaps rewrite it terms of the main code as stated in the openingspost? is there also a way that we can have rectangles where we put in the pincode so as follows: [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]?

Comment: You could have separate text inputs, each for a digit, which would make your boxes. can make it so that when one text input is filled it auto focuses to the next text input etc etc.
Here is an example of a login screen you could use for help: https://gist.github.com/Cheaterman/812203a74f8c552a4918
I think I helped with the issue of focus and triggering events when you type in your text input. Someone else may help rewrite your code, however I unfortunately can't.
If you want to ask another question with a more specific line of enquiry/code I'd be happy to help.
Thanks.